# subprocess.Popen not working in ubuntu (working fine in Windows)

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, popen

I am right now in the same directory in which the file "lookup.csv" is residing.

I have tried following commands in Python 2.7:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen("lookup.csv", shell = True)
```

The above is producing the following error:

> lookup.csv : not found

I have double-checked for the working directory, tried lot of available troubleshooting options given in StakExchange, tried the same in Windows (and surprisingly it was working there), what more can I do?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Please post the complete stacktrace. Why are you using `shell=True`?

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason why this should work on Windows because `lookup.csv` clearly is a file which you want to open with `open` whereas `subprocess.Popen` creates a new process for working with the `lookup.csv` binary. Maybe Windows handles process failure differently.

Comment: Hi, I simply want python script to open a csv file in csv mode (Libre office)